# Restful Service Message is not shown

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to make a simple restful service example. As you can see on the following image:

[image]

When server is started, I open up link **localhost:8080/ws/rs/hello**, however, page opens but message is not shown. What am I missing or how can i fix this ?

Comment: Use Poster/PostMan addon to show message. Type the address on URL and Click on GET...

You will also get to know server side error from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling with Jersey 2 nowadays and i had the same problem with you. Lots of sites claim that web.xml is not necessary but i couldn't make a working example like you.

Instead of `ApplicationPath`, define your url-pattern inside your web.xml. 
This is a sample :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestWithJersey2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.cihan.service.foo</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestWithJersey2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jersey2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when calling change `/jersey2/*` to `/ws/*` and of course the `<param-value>`

Comment: Thank you very mucg for that info. That was also my final idea to try that out. I will go try that now and inform you soon!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat 7 then probably doing this should work - 
**@ApplicationPath("/*")**
And the URL would be changed accordingly.

If it is not Tomcat/Jetty, this should fine anyways.

Also you can try keeping a black web.xml file in your project and that should suffice.